# Stopping scheduled reports by freezing user account

Tags: administration, configuration, scheduled, roles

When a user account in Salesforce is frozen (using the freeze feature) does this prevent them getting scheduled reports that they would normally have received? For example, UserA has a role SalesManager and dashboard "SalesTeam" is scheduled to send email daily to role SalesManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments from product management on this idea:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kyGeAAI

It looks like at the moment, frozen users will still receive scheduled reports via email.